# Using short codes- need spacing when columns stack on smaller devices

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using short codes to enter into a widget on Word Press. The columns stack perfectly, but I'd like space between them.  I've tried this below (including mb-3) but it isn't working:

```
[counter title="Years in Business" value="30" title_size="32px" title_color="black" value_size="65px"  value_color="#bb2025" icon="fa-calendar" icon_size="28px" class="col-md-4 mb-3"]

[counter title="Satisfied Customers" value="285" title_size="32px" title_color="black" value_size="65px"  value_color="#bb2025" icon="fa-group" icon_size="28px" class="col-md-4 mb-3"]

[counter title="Tons of Sand Monthly" value="30" title_size="32px" title_color="black" value_size="65px"  value_color="#bb2025" icon="fa-truck" icon_size="28px" class="col-md-4 mb-3"]
```